# Cannot get PHP to execute MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

Why doesn't my MySQL code work from PHP. However if I return the SQL and paste it into the SQL console the rows update accordingly.

**SQL**

```
UPDATE propertypriority 
   SET prioritylevel = '8' 
 WHERE roomtypecode = '1184'; 

UPDATE property 
   SET prioritylevel = '8' 
 WHERE roomtypecode = '1184';
```

**PHP**

```
$sql = "UPDATE propertypriority 
           SET prioritylevel = '".$demotionvalue."' 
         WHERE roomtypecode = '".$row['roomtypecode']."'; "
       ."UPDATE property
            SET prioritylevel = '".$demotionvalue."' 
          WHERE roomtypecode = '".$row['roomtypecode']."'; ";
```

Comment: Why do two tables contain identical information?!

Comment: im a noob and im trying to work out how to cascade on update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-sql-injection.htm

'Fortunately, if you use MySQL, the mysql_query() function does not permit query stacking, or executing multiple queries in a single function call. If you try to stack queries, the call fails.'

so maybe try breaking it into two queries

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to look into wrapping your SQL statements into a transaction.

[This page from the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php) has a example for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using mysqli?  If so, depending on how you execute the query, it's not going to allow you to execute two statements with one command.

Comment: I definitely think that including ";" in a SQL command is the problem.  Most definitely.